# 原因のわからないバグの特定方法について

Tags: swift, ios

一通りアプリを製作して、実機で作動させています。
実機でも問題なく全ての機能が想定通り動くことを確認しました。
しかし、ある程度の期間、そのアプリを実機で使用していると、アプリが起動しなくなります。
(Launchscreenが一瞬出て、すぐに落ちます。)

そこで、実機のiPhoneをxcodeに繋げ、再ビルドさせるとまた、問題なく起動し、動作します。
CoreData内のデータが悪さをしているのかと思い、中身を確認しましたが、データは問題なさそうです。最初のViewでは、tableとadmobの設定をした後、CoreDataからtableに表示させるための
データを持ってきてるだけの単純な処理です。

xcodeに繋げてる状態で、エラーが起こればエラーコードを読んで対応することが可能なのですが、今回のように、いつ発生するかわからないバグについて、どのようにデバッグしたら良いかアドバイスを頂けないでしょうか。

Comment: FirebaseのCrashReportingなどを使ってみてはいかがでしょうか?

Answer (score 1):

USBケーブルで端末を Mac に繋ぎ、Xcode のメニューバーから Window > Devices を開いて、接続した端末を選択して View Device Logs をクリックしてクラッシュログの一覧を開きます。
Process 名と日付から目的のアプリのクラッシュログを探し、ログを読んで下さい。

開発している Mac で入れたアプリであれば、クラッシュ時のコードの関数名や行番号が表示されると思います。